# __call method not get executed when try to call non existent function in yii controller?

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php
class ReportsController extends CController
{
    public function __call($name,$argument)
    {
        echo "test";
    }

}
?>
```

This is my Yii controller class and when calling `index.php?r=reports/test` URL it has to call the `__call` method as test method is not exists but it gives error `The system is unable to find the requested action test` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `missingAction` method in your controller,

As said @xdazz,  it checks if method exists and if not it calls `missingAction` method.

```
//This method is invoked when the controller cannot find the requested action.

public function missingAction($actionID)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is depending on the implement of the framework.

For example, if the framework implement the code like:

```
If (!method_exists($controller, $action)) {
  throw new Exception("The system is unable to find the requested action $action");
}
```